# knockout.js how to prevent model from updating template.

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, preserve

Hi i have the following field

```
<span id="myText" data=bind="text: name">default value</span>
```

I want to be able to initialize the value with like

```
var model = {
   name = ko.observable("");
}
ko.apply(model);
```

However, i do not want the value "default value" to change. I want to preserve the original value.

How can i go about doing this?

Comment: Preserve it until the value of name is changed? You would need either a computed value, or a special binding that read "default value" until its source was non-empty. There is no way to stop the template from updating the way you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a custom binding to populate your observable from the element's current innerText.

Something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.textWithInit = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable("innerText" in element ? element.innerText : element.textContent);   
    },
    update: ko.bindingHandlers.text.update
};
```

You could add more error handling to this as well (handle observables & non-obseravbles, etc.)

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/x4XJW/